# Exposing command line directory list as REST API shows blank page

Tags: java, rest

Am trying to expose the following command line directory list as a RestApi with plain text .It does print the list of c directory in console with system.out.println but does not show the output on the uri page,its empty.Example:

> ```
>     http://localhost:Project/show/dir
> ```

is blank. Any suggestions as to where am going wrong. Below is the code snippet.

```
public class ShowDirectory  {

String s=null;

public String showDir() {
    try{

         Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
         Process pr = rt.exec("cmd /c dir");

         BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader
(pr.getInputStream()));

         String line=null;
StringBuffer directory= new StringBuffer();
                                                     while((line=input.readLine()) != null) {
directory.append(line+ "\n");

             System.out.println(line);
         }

         int exitVal = pr.waitFor();
         System.out.println("Exited with error code "+exitVal);

     } catch(Exception e) {
         System.out.println(e.toString());
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
    return s;
 }
}
```

Service Class:

```
@Path("show")

public class StartDirectory {

@GET
@Path("dir")
@Produces({"text/plain","application/xml","application/json"})
@Consumes({ "application/xml", "application/json",
        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" })
public String getLog(){
    ShowDirectory status = new ShowDirectory();
    return status.showDir();


}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning null from showDir. All of your output is being sent to standard out.

Comment: :Thanks for the reply real quick. Could you please elaborate a little.

Comment: @user2821894 You're calling `System.out.println` rather than appending  to your return value `s`. By the way, you should use a `StringBuilder` for better performance, but that's the least of your problems right now.

Comment: :I did tried appending but no use the requested uri still shows blank page. Edited my code above.

Comment: You still have `return s;`. Change that to `return directory.toString();`.

Comment: Thanks Brian. It worked. I really appreciate it.You saved my day.